# iMessage message freeze

Tags: ios, icloud, messages, performance

I have an iPod Touch 4G and my software is updated to iOS 6.1. I was messaging someone then suddenly it gave me an error saying the message was not sent and I had to re-try sending the message.

After that my iMessage freezes if I go into that same conversation. I cannot delete that conversation because if I go back (does not freeze if my screen is not in a conversation) and press edit then delete, it reappears every 5 seconds.

How can I troubleshoot iMessage on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

The same exact thing is happening to me. I opened my imessage app and it's just blank white. I tried deleting from task bar, resetting, shutting off, logging out from imessage on settings, resetting wifi, but nothing seems to work. It's even updated to 6.1 and it's just frozen there.

The only option is to restore your device to reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has been [having problems with its iMessage servers today](http://www.theverge.com/2012/10/25/3555482/apple-imessage-down-ios-users-unable-send-messages), which may be what you're running into.

If you're experiencing freezes, you can also try force quitting the app, by double clicking the home button (when you're not using Messages), holding down the iMessage icon in the switcher bar at the bottom until the icons start jiggling, then tap the red and white minus sign on the Messages icon. Then try reopening it.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to troubleshoot Messages (or any other iCloud issue) is to disable all networking (AirPlane Mode or similar on computers) and to shut down the device.

At that point, I can power up the software and go about the cleaning and know if there are problems, it's due to the specific data that is on the device and not some issue communicating to the cloud.

While the device is rebooting, check the system status for any service outages: http://apple.com/support/systemstatus

Once it reboots, start an organized troubleshooting process: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204065